# How can I check if busybox is working properly?

Tags: busybox

I have Busybox installed, but I suspect that it does not work properly. 
Total Commander ADB plugin invokes `busybox mv -f` and `busybox rm -f` commands, but it seems to fail silently.

Is there a reasonable way how to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["How do i know if I have busybox?"](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-hacks-help/24081-how-do-i-know-if-i-have-busybox.html)

> Open Terminal Emulator and type "busybox". If it gives you a giant list of command options, it's installed. If it says "Command not found", it's not.

**edit** Rather than putting this in the comments: you could also try `su` to become root followed by `busybox`, `busybox --version`, `busybox --help` or anything that will give you some feedback and some clues as to what's going on.

Comment: It gives me nothing. No error, but no text either. Thats why I am confused.

Comment: Then it prints `busybox` and nothing else.

Comment: Titanium backup does a check and displays busybox information. Might be handy. Try the above in terminal emulator, but try SU first, as I think busybox commands need super user access!

Comment: I think it is completely broken. `su` followed by any of `busybox`, `busybox --version`, `busybox --help` does not do anything (but repeat the command to the output). No error, no output.

Comment: @RossC Where exactly in Titanium Backup? I cannot find it.

Comment: It is on the play store. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup

Comment: @RossC I have it. I just do not see the busybox check and information in the application.

Comment: It should have 'Root Access' and a tick beside it and the text "OK ->tap for more information<-". When you click that it should show your busybox version!

Comment: @RossC Can you also put it as answer? It was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have figured that my Busybox is broken as I have suspected. I ended up re-flashing the ROM.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer above:

[Titanium Backup from Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) You can install this, and it will have Root > OK "->Tap for more Information <-." Once you click on this it will display whether your root is correct and your current busybox version.

Alternatively, using terminal commands like in the accepted answer, you may need to enter the SuperUser command first with "SU" in the terminal emulator of your choice. The prompt will change to a # sign to show you are now in SuperUser. The alternative SUDO, will give superuser on a command by command basis, e.g. SUDO Busybox.

As with the OP, sometimes reflashing the ROM is the easiest or you can use the  [Busy Box Installer from Play Store.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.busybox.installer)  (I have not tried this personally)